# How to make a dependent local package application folders visible

Tags: dart, dart-editor

[image]Using the information at https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#path-packages

I have gotten one app epimss_design to depend on epimss_podo. However, I wanted to now edit a class in the dependent package epimss_podo, but now it is only represented by an empty folder in the editor. I was expecting the epimss_podo folder structure with its lib folder to be visible. According to the information 'Any changes you make to the dependent package are seen immediately'.

Question | How do I get the epimss_podo visible which will allow me to work with it?

I am using Polymer 0.12.0-dev and Dart Editor version 1.6.0.dev_03_00 (DEV) Dart SDK version 1.6.0-dev.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open both packages as folders separately in DartEditor.

When you change something in `epimss_podo` this change will take effect immediately when you reload for example `epimss_design/web/index.html` which uses some code from `epimss_podo/lib/some_file.dart`

Comment: Thanks Gunter. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Given the folder structure above, I am trying to use the relative path instead of the absolute for the path param without much success. Even though I read the docs, the relative path still does not work, and I don't like the idea of using the absolute path.

Comment: Your package folder needs at least a `pubspec.yaml` file with the package name. The package name in `pubspec.yaml` of `epimss_podo` must be the same as the dependency name used in `epimss_design`